# Shows error when run 'rails g rails_admin:install' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I was trying to install rails_admin gem in my rails app.I followed this [document](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). But when I run the command `rails g rails_admin:install` it shows the following error.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 51535
       ?  Where do you want to mount rails_admin? Press <enter> for [admin] > /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:20:in `readline': Input/output error - read (Errno::EIO)
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:20:in `readline'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:7:in `readline'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:395:in `ask_simply'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:68:in `ask'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:59:in `ask'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/rails_admin-0.8.1/lib/generators/rails_admin/utils.rb:13:in `ask_for'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/rails_admin-0.8.1/lib/generators/rails_admin/install_generator.rb:13:in `install'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in `generate_or_destroy'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/home/Neethu/Projects/Rails/Personal/SampleRailsAdmin/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/voiceover/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I am using gemset with Ruby version 2.2.3 and Rails version 4.2.5.

Please suggest some solution.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the system it got worked !!!